# Using viewport Height causes pixel line for some sections with some screen sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design

Edit: Solution - I added 3 properties.

```
section{
    **height: calc(86vh + 2px);**
}
:target {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -14vh; 
    visibility: hidden;
    **margin-top: 2px;**
}
#spacer{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 14vh;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    **margin-bottom: -2px;**
}
```

Here is the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/JohnWeb/9m2ovuyo/

I'm using vh to size the 3 sections I have. But at some screen sizes it will leave a pixel line above the first 2 sections, but the 3rd will be the right size. Last time I checked 14vh + 86vh = 100vh = 100% ...

```
section{
    height: 86vh;
}

#spacer{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 14vh;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
```

[image]

^ Below the green section and above the aqua section ^

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate the white line you talk about. When does it happen? Browser? Screen Size?

Comment: in the fiddle if you resize height it should appear/disappear as you make the view section taller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem does not occur in all the screens, so it's difficult to give correct solution but there is a hack for such kind of situation. You can use negative margin to leave 2px gap .

```
#spacer{
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

and same amount of height i.e 2px you add to your below section with aqua colour other wise it will leave 2px gap from bottom. Through this aqua colour section will overlap 2px below header section, that will solve any unconditional gap between them. Bootstrap also uses similar kind of technique to remove any possible layout error by creating 15px gutter.

Comment: So I had to do what you proposed, first off, TY!!! In order to solve most situations I also added margin-top: 2px to the :target rule, this solved the situation in almost all situations.

Comment: I didn't notice this, but I also used calc() for the section size as well, so it was definitely a multi-faceted solution lol.